# How to Fetch Every Next 100 rows from DataTable C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I am working on Windows Form Application  i have a DataTable Which contains 1000 rows and for paging my DataGridView i am fetching first 100 records from DataTable like this

```
DataTable rec = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(x => x["RegNo"]).Take(100).CopyToDataTable();
```

I have also tried this

```
DataTable recc = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(x => x["RegNo"]).Take(100).Skip(100).CopyToDataTable();
```

**Question:**
how to fetch next 100 records from DataTable when user click on next page and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip and take.

```
DataTable rec = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(x => x["RegNo"]).Skip(100).Take(100).CopyToDataTable();
```

You can have a variable that tracks current page.

```
var currPage = 1;
var page_size = 100;
var skip = currPage * page_size; //if 100 is page size......

    DataTable rec = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(x => x["RegNo"]).Skip(skip).Take(page_size).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Skip()` and `Take()` functions. Better option would be to send page index and rows count per page as parameter to your function:

```
DataTable rec = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                       .OrderBy(x => x["RegNo"])
                       .Skip(rowsCount * pageIndex)
                       .Take(rowsCount)
                       .CopyToDataTable();
```